# How to remove load_video and gfxmode from grub?

Tags: grub2, encryption, grub-efi

due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1386005) my computer can't boot with `load_video` or `gfxmode`

How can I edit grub to remove these 2 lines?

```
$ more /etc/default/grub 
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash noplymouth"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
#GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: After backing the file up maybe take  at /etc/grub.d/00_header. In 16.04 an area of interest to you could be lines 234 & maybe 235. If removing one or both lines also remove space they occupied. Any edits need sudo update-grub to take affect. Note that several years back I removed what's now on line 234 to fix something though I also removed 3 lines in /etc/grub.d/10_linux (- in 16.04 they'd be lines 150 - 152. ) If editing any of these templates I'd first back them up & be prepared/able to restore orig. file(s)

Answer (score 2):

Per code in /etc/grub.d/00_header, it looks like you need to set `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` to avoid gfxterm

It's also possible to set `GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND` to a specific value to avoid a lot of video modules, but I'm not sure what actual value is the best thing to use here to avoid video altogether, cf. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html